# How to read a specific amount of characters

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I can get the characters from console with this code:
Displays 2 characters each time in a new line

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char ch[3] = "";

    ifstream file("example.txt");

    while (file.read(ch, sizeof(ch)-1))
    {
       cout << ch << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is, if the set of characters be odd it doesn't displays the last character in the text file!

my text file contains this:
abcdefg

it doesn't displays the letter g in the console
its displaying this:

- ab
- cd
- ef

I wanna display like this:

- ab
- cd
- ef
- g

I wanna use this to read 1000 characters at a time for a large file so i don't wanna read character by character, It takes a lot of time, but it has a problem if u can fix it or have a better suggestion, share it with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code should work:

```
while (file) {
    file.read(ch, sizeof(ch) - 1);
    int number_read_chars = file.gcount();
    // print chars here ...
}
```

By moving the `read` call into the loop, you'll be able to handle the last call, where too few characters are available. The `gcount` method will provide you with the information how many characters were actually read by the last unformatted input operation, e.g. `read`.

Please note, when reading less than `sizeof(ch)` chars, you manually have to insert a `NUL` character at the position returned by `gcount`, if you intend to use the buffer as a C string, as those are null terminated:

```
ch[file.gcount()] = '\0';
```

Comment: Don't forget to null terminate when reading less than 2 characters.